# Create custom URL with different levels

Tags: posts, urls

I am new to Wordpress and used to Drupal. In drupal I could put any url for any post. It is not bound to category or tags.

for example, pages in any category can have  any structure of different urls like below

```
1. /page/about/vision.html
2. /page/about/topics
3. /page/employee/motivation/artcle/1.html
```

But I noticed, in wordpress I can not modify the levels other than what I put in "Permalink Settings"'s custom structure section. After save the setting on it, i can not create more levels in page.

Any one worked in Drupal will understand the question easily.

What my question is, is there any plugins that can allow me create any URL or aliases with any levels to any post?

Answer (score 0):

On a very basic level, sub-pages inherit the URL segment of their parent page.

A bit more complex, when creating custom taxonomies and custom post types you can define their slug for the WP rewrite engine. The documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies

Neither is exactly what you're looking for... Writing to .htaccess wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: mhh yes, creating custom post will be terrible for each different types of urls. need to handle in a different way. lets think. thanks for the repl.